# How can i view all cache in Http in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know i can use this

```
var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
cache.get('http://example.com/api/users.json');
```

But i want to know what other data cache has.

I tried

`console.log(cache)` but it only gives function names not the actual data in cache

I tried this page

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

In the example they use keys to get data

```
<div ng-repeat="key in keys">
    <span ng-bind="key"></span>
    <span>: </span>
    <b ng-bind="cache.get(key)"></b>
  </div>
```

but i want to get those keys which reside in cache. i mean something like

```
cache.getKeys()
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Comment: @Donal i already read that page but i  am not able to show in console how many urls cache has already got from previous http requests.

Comment: What does `cache.info()` give you?

Comment: @Donal it only give me `id: $http,  size: 5`

Comment: What does `cache.get('$http')` give you?

Comment: @Donal it gives this  `Object { put=function(),  get=function(),  remove=function(),  more...} `

Comment: did the code for reading the cacheInfo that is listed on the documentation page not give you what you want?

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in cache.info()">
    <span ng-bind="key"></span>
    <span>: </span>
    <b ng-bind="value"></b>
  </div>`

Comment: @Claies it only gave me `id: $http, size: 5`   The keys in example codes are hard coded but i want to get all keys which are in cache. I can get cache.get(key) but for that i need to know the key , which i don't know

Comment: That is the point of the repeat, it should be showing all the keys and values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the internal implementation of `$cacheFactoryProvider` you'll pretty quickly find that the `data` variable is never exposed in its raw state.

As such, the only real way of getting said data is to modify the Angular JS source - or decorate the provider.

---

Now, I've attempted it - it *"works™"*, but I will note that it is **just** a Proof of concept. You could probably take this further, and/or implement it in a fork of angular *(better yet, send a PR)* and run their spec suite to figure out if and how you managed to break stuff.

Anyway, here it is - I've tried to document the steps I've taken as best I can.

```
app.config(function ($provide) {

  /**
   * Store a reference to the original return value
   * of $cacheFactory(cacheId, options).
   *
   * Used later in referencing 'native' methods. 
   */
  var originalCacheFactory;

  $provide.decorator('$cacheFactory', function ($delegate) {
    /**
     * Setup a caches holder.
     */
    var caches = {};

    /**
     * Dont overwrite the original
     */
    if (!originalCacheFactory) {
      originalCacheFactory = $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
    }

    /**
     * Setup a new cacheFactory method.
     * Take the original return value of $delegate(cacheId, options)
     * and extend it with some overriden methods.
     *
     * `put` should also push our data into a local `data` variable.
     * `getAll()` returns the entire data pool for the given cache.
     *
     */
    function cacheFactory (cacheId, options) {
      var data = {};

      return caches[cacheId] = angular.extend($delegate.apply(null, arguments), {
        put: function (k, v) {
          /**
           * Store away the values in
           * our own `data` variable, presented by
           * .getAll.
           */
          if (!data[cacheId]) {
            data[cacheId] = {};
          }

          data[cacheId][k] = v;

          /**
           * Run the original .put method.
           */
          originalCacheFactory.put.apply(null, arguments);
        },
        getAll: function () {
          return data[cacheId];
        }
      });
    }

    /**
     * Re-implement the $cacheFactory.get(id)
     * method.
     */
    cacheFactory.get = function (id) {
      return caches[id];
    };

    /**
     * Re-implement the $cacheFactory.info()
     * method.
     */
    cacheFactory.info = function () {
      var info = {};
      forEach(caches, function(cache, cacheId) {
        info[cacheId] = cache.info();
      });
      return info;
    };

    /**
     * Return our new cacheFactory function.
     */
    return cacheFactory;
  });
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Log the contents of the $templateCache.
 */
app.run(function ($templateCache, $cacheProvider, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function () {
    console.log($templateCache.getAll());
  });

  // or

  $timeout(function () {
    console.log($cacheProvider.get('templates').getAll());
  });
});
```

---

Here's a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nikuyafajo/1/edit) showcasing the end result. Pop open the console and you will see the console output of three stored templates in the $templateCache.

---

### With all of that said and done;

- **An issue has already been posted @ angular:** [angular.js#3797](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3797)
- [angular-cache by @jmdobry](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) has already invented this wheel and replaced the $cacheFactory.

  - [.keySet()](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#cachekeyset)
  - [.keys()](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#cachekeys)

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to find a list of all urls that something has had before and unfortunately had to dip into angular itself. If you can get access to the angular you're including you can add the ability to do what you want. First find the `$CacheFactoryProvider` function, then where it actually returns the cache like so `return caches[cacheId] = {` add a new parameter on the object before put called data and set it to data like this `data: data,`. Currently angular only keeps it local. This way what you can do is get everything that the cache has stored via a object. So you'll have the keys be the urls.